# Using a function within mapply to create and save scatterplots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use `mapply` to automate saving scatterplots from `ggplot` to a folder.

To do this I have created lists of my x variable and y variable, as well as a list of the grouping variable I would like to colour my points by.

I then tried creating a `function`, and calling the function with `mapply` but the only output saved is a single blank image of the last variable in the list. Below is an example dataset.

```
df <- data.frame("ID" = 1:16)
df$VarA <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,14,NA_real_,NA_real_,NA_real_,16)
df$VarB <- c(10,0,0,0,12,12,12,12,0,14,NA_real_,14,16,16,16,16)
df$VarC <- c(10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16)
df$VarD <- c(10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16,10,12,14,16)
df$ControlVarA <- factor(c("Group_1","Group_1","Group_1","Group_1","Group_1", "Group_1",
                   "Group_2","Group_2","Group_2","Group_2","Group_2","Group_2",
                   "Group_2","Group_2","Group_2","Group_2")) 
df$ControlVarB <- factor(c("Group_1","Group_1","Group_1","Group_1","Group_1", "Group_1",
                    "Group_1","Group_1","Group_1","Group_1","Group_2","Group_2",
                    "Group_2","Group_2","Group_2","Group_2")) 
df$ControlVarC <- factor(c("Group_2","Group_2","Group_2","Group_2","Group_1", "Group_1",
                    "Group_2","Group_2","Group_2","Group_2","Group_2","Group_2",
                    "Group_2","Group_2","Group_2","Group_2"))
```

Below is the code I used to call the lists for the x, y and colouring variable.

```
x_lists <- df %>% select(VarA:VarB) %>% colnames(.)
y_lists <- df %>% select(VarC:VarD) %>% colnames(.)
ControlVar_list <- df %>% select(contains("ControlVar")) %>% colnames(.)
```

Below is the `function` I have created and the `mapply`

```
save_plots <- function(dataset, x, y, z) {
  
  first_plot <- ggplot(dataset) +
    geom_point(data = subset(dataset, .data[[z]] == 'Group_1'),
               aes(x = .data[[x]], y = .data[[y]], color = .data[[z]], size = 3)) +
    geom_point(data = subset(dataset, .data[[z]] == 'Group_2'),
               aes(x = .data[[x]], y = .data[[y]], color = .data[[z]], size = 3)) +
    geom_smooth(aes(x = .data[[x]], y = .data[[y]], size = 0), method = "lm", colour="black", size=0.5) +
    stat_cor(aes(x = .data[[x]], y = .data[[y]], color = .data[[z]],
                 label = ..rr.label..), 
             label.y.npc="top", label.x.npc = "left", method = "pearson",
             size = 5) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("#C5BEC9", "#F2642b", "#F2642b")) +
    labs(title = "test",
         x = "VarA",
         y = "VarB",
         colour = "") +
    guides(size = FALSE, color = FALSE) +
    theme_bw(base_size = 14)
  
  ggsave(sprintf("C:\\Documents\\%s.tiff", y), first_plot)
  grDevices::dev.off()
}

mapply(save_plots, x_lists, y_lists, ControlVar_list, MoreArgs = list(dataset = df))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.data` will not work with base R `subset` function. Try using `dplyr::filter`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)

save_plots <- function(dataset, x, y, z) {
  
  first_plot <- ggplot(dataset) +
    geom_point(data = filter(dataset, .data[[z]] == 'Group_1'),
               aes(x = .data[[x]], y = .data[[y]], color = .data[[z]], size = 3)) +
    geom_point(data = filter(dataset, .data[[z]] == 'Group_2'),
               aes(x = .data[[x]], y = .data[[y]], color = .data[[z]], size = 3)) +
    geom_smooth(aes(x = .data[[x]], y = .data[[y]], size = 0), method = "lm", colour="black", size=0.5) +
    stat_cor(aes(x = .data[[x]], y = .data[[y]], color = .data[[z]],
                 label = ..rr.label..), 
             label.y.npc="top", label.x.npc = "left", method = "pearson",
             size = 5) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("#C5BEC9", "#F2642b", "#F2642b")) +
    labs(title = "test",
         x = "VarA",
         y = "VarB",
         colour = "") +
    guides(size = FALSE, color = FALSE) +
    theme_bw(base_size = 14)
  
  ggsave(sprintf("%s.tiff", y), first_plot)
  grDevices::dev.off()
}
```